# ADB Debugging over wifi not connecting

Tags: wi-fi, adb, usb-debugging

So I am trying to connect my device to adb over wifi. I have been following this tutorial 
http://codetheory.in/android-debug-bridge-adb-wireless-debugging-over-wi-fi/

I have been doing this

```
adb tcpip 5556
adb connect <ip address>:5556
```

what i get back is

```
cannot connect to <ip address>:5556:5556
```

if i do not include the port

```
adb connect <ip address>
```

then i get this

```
cannot connect to <ip address>:5555
```

Does anyone have any  ideas?

Comment: Maybe `adb tcpip 5555` if that's the default.

Comment: Does the device have to be rooted to do this?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Is the device reachable in the network? Can you ping it? Is the IP address correct? That error shows up when I can't reach the device due to its Wi-Fi being disabled/ a firewall in Android is blocking the connection / IP address is not of device.

Comment: So I think the problem had to do with the network I was on. When I moved to a different network I was able to connect.